# Как выбрать из массива массивов по одному элементу, чтобы новый массив был упорядочен?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть массив из массивов , например такой:

1,1,N
   10,13,N
   3,N
   5,N
   N
   N
   N
   12,N
   10,13,N
   14,N
   15,N

То есть в каждом массиве  есть в конце null.

Надо выбрать из каждого массива  по одному элементу так, чтобы:

- Все элементы, имеющие значения были упорядочены по возрастанию
- Количество элементов должно быть наибольшим
- Сумма разниц между значением элемента и его индексом должна быть наименьшей

То есть в результате должно получиться что то вроде:

1,N,3,5,N,N,N,12,13,14,15

Я реализовал это так. Нашел все варианты, в которых числа идут по порядку, потом выбрал из них лучший (по количеству ненулевых элементов и тд). Все было хорошо, но когда в массиве оказывается 100 по 1-15 элементов в каждом, программа вылетает по таймауту, так и не просчитав все варианты )

Comment: напишите ваш вариант решения, будет понятнее.

Comment: @Romario, Очень сомневаюсь, там многослойные линки. Да и зачем вам мой вариант? вы свой предложите

Answer (score 1):

Первые 2 пункта задача решаются например динамическим программированием + структура данных. Общая идея - создаём дерево (отрезков / Фенвика) которое для `i` позиции хранит максимальную длину последовательности, оканчивающейся в `i` и удовлетворяющая пункту `1`. Теперь мы берём `j` строку и перебираем что из неё поставить (какое-либо значение или ничего). Для каждого значения мы берём максимум в дереве от `0` или если есть отрицательные элементы то от `-бесконечности` до элемента (не включительно как я понял). Сохраняем отдельно. Идём ещё раз по строке `j` и если значение в дереве соответствующее элементы меньше или равно сохранённому то в дерево на это место сохранённое `+ 1`. Если равно сохранённому +1 то нужно обработать отдельно (в конце опишу). 
Максимальное значение в дереве и есть ответ на первые 2 пункта.

С 3 пунктом всё не намного сложнее, просто нужно хранить в дереве не только максимум, но и уже посчитанную разность сумм на начальной последовательности, при этом перетирая если значение стало меньше.

Восстановить ответ уже тривиальная задача, можно просто хранить в дереве элемент откуда туда пришли.

Решение не сильно сложное в реализации, но подумать есть над чем, если что непонятно по ответу спрашивайте.

Comment: А как посчитать максимальную длину последовательности, оканчивающуюся в i? ))

Comment: мы её не считаем а поддерживаем с помощью дерева.

Comment: Так... есть массив 8 5 1 6 8 4 3 5 6. Нужно удалить из него минимальное количество элементов, чтобы массив стал упорядоченным. Я не совсем понял как строить эти деревья. Что у нас в данном случае будет в вершине 4 и в вершине 7? Почему?

Comment: пошагово [8]=1 [5]=1 [1] = 1 [6]=2 [8]=3 [4]=2 [3]=2 [5]=3 [6]=4